# In C# is there a way to use properties with arrays?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, properties

The way I understand it, C# properties are methods that have the `get` and `set` accessors.

```
class MyClass  
{  
    private int x;  
    public int X  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return x;  
        }  
        set  
        {  
            x = value;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

I can call the property of the class in a script (and its accessors) with

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.X = 10;
Debug.Log(mc.X); //returns 10
```

To my knowledge, however, I can pass only one value to the property.
Is there a way to pass arrays? Something like

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.X = new int[] { 1, 2 }; //throws an error
Debug.Log(mc.X[0]); //I'd like it to return 1
```

This throws an error of course. I wonder if it's possible to do it any other way.

Comment: Then you should make the property an array, no?

Comment: If you want the property to be an array, you'd need to declare it as `public int[] X` (with field to match); you can't store an array in an int field

Comment: Make the type of `X` and `x` an array instead `int[]`

Comment: Thank you all! Yeah, in retrospect is was a stupid question. I'm still learning and I still got to get the hang of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is simple - use `int[]` instead of `int`

```
class MyClass
{
    private int[] x;
    public int[] X
    {
        get
        {
            return x;
        }
        set
        {
            x = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Also you might consider using auto property instead just like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    public int[] X { get; set; }
}
```

You might also want to take a look at the Lists and read some basics ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sure, just make the property an array or list also:

```
class MyClass  
{  
    // in general a list should never be null, but could be empty, or without values.
    // thats why we initialize the field here
    private List<int> x = new List<int>();  

    public List<int> X  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return x;  
        }  
        set  
        {  
            x = value;  
        }  
    }  
}
```

then you could do:

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.X.Add(3);
obj.X.Add(6);

// (or use AddRange() to add another list or array of values

// Then loop the list and output values:

foreach(int x in obj.X)
{
   Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Here's a dotnetfiddle for the above code:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/T2FrQ0

Comment: Thanks! That's pretty useful to know. I didn't realize you could also treat the property as a list, this could be even better.

Comment: When I try to run the script, it says "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at line `obj.X.Add(3);`. Is it normal? What should I do?